# Highcharts Plot background

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to create a Highcharts plot background like the picture below? It's important it will adjust when the plot is zoomed in/out.

E.g. Using radialGradient, but without the "gradient" between the colors.

[image: Highcharts background]

Answer (score 4):

The example below is only a starting point using [SVGrenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#arc):

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
}, function(chart) {
  var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0], 
  y = yAxis.top+yAxis.height, 
  x = chart.plotLeft,
  h = yAxis.height;
  svg = chart.renderer;
  
  svg.arc(x,y,h/3,0,1.5*Math.PI,0)
    .attr({
    fill: '#dce6f2',
    'stroke-width': 0,
    zIndex: -1
  }).add();
  
  svg.arc(x,y,2*h/3,0,1.5*Math.PI,0)
    .attr({
    fill: '#c5d8f1',
    'stroke-width': 0,
    zIndex: -2
  }).add();
  
  svg.arc(x,y,h,0,1.5*Math.PI,0)
    .attr({
    fill: '#95b3d7',
    'stroke-width': 0,
    zIndex: -3
  }).add();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. You're nearly there, but hiding one series makes the other one move out of its sector. See https://imgur.com/a/Z6Z1e

Comment: Yes, it's only an example, you have to adapt to your needs and write the logic you want

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it to be x/y symmetrical, then it's easy:

```
chart: {
    backgroundColor: {
      radialGradient: {
        cx: 0,
        cy: 1,
        r: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#dce6f2'],
        [.25, '#dce6f2'],
        [.25, '#c5d8f1'],
        [.50, '#c5d8f1'], 
        [.50, '#95b3d7'],
        [.75, '#95b3d7'],
        [.75, '#fff'],
        [1, '#fff']
      ]
    },
    type: 'line'
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndjnx2eh/9/

This will scale with the size of the chart.

If you need it to always be a quarter circle, it's not so easy.